# Why isn't my tableview visible?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm an sdk newbie, so please forgive the simplicity of this question.  Here's the scenario:

I used the Utility Based application template because I like the flip effect of the info button. I changed the info button to a round rect button and made a copy of it that to have two round rect buttons on my first view. I modified the flipside view to display a picture and that functionality works fine.  For the second button I wanted it to flip to a tableview underneath the navigation bar.  I added a navViewController for the navigation bar and a TableViewController for the tableview. I made a nib for that View, added the tableview, hooked up all the appropriate connections, but when I run it, the flip works fine, but there is no tableview displayed. What I mean by no tableview is it is blank. No lines or anything, just a blank navigation bar at top and blank white space. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With limited information you have given here:

**Potential Problem 1** - First Level UIViewController is not linked
If you open NIB file in interface builder where you have drag and dropped NavigationViewController, you will see small disclosure triangle. If you expand that you will see NavigationBar and UIViewController. Select the UIViewController and change it to name of the TableViewController.

The NIB file will change and say View Loaded from YourTableViewController.

**Potential Problem 2** - You have to do addSubView or insertSubView and pass in [navigationController view]

If you post some code it may be helpful.

Hope this Helps!